# Die subjektive Bedeutung von sollen

Tags: modal-verb, future

Ich unterrichte schon seit ungefähr 4 Jahren Deutsch als Fremdsprache und kenne mich deshalb eigentlich mit der Grammatik ziemlich gut aus. Ich hätte aber mal eine Frage zu dem Modalverb "sollen" bzw. zu dem subjektiven Gebrauch des Verbs. Es ist ja so, dass "sollen" im Deutschen oft dazu benutzt wird, gehörte oder gelesene Informationen ungewertet wiederzugeben. Dabei kann es sich um anrüchige Gerüchte über einen Kollegen handeln (Petra soll mit dem Chef ins Bett gestiegen sein.) oder aber auch um den wissenschaftlichen Stand der Dinge (Flavonoide sollen den Blutdruck senken.).

Der subjektive Gebrauch von "sollen" ist im Präsens und in der Vergangenheit relativ unkompliziert. In der Vergangenheit kann es in Nebensätzen, besonders in Verbindung mit dem Passiv, zu extrem langen Verbblöcken kommen (, dass Paul von der Chefin geküsst worden sein soll.). Und mit Modalverben im objektiven Gebrauch kann es sogar Verwirrung darüber geben, wo die einzelnen Verben genau stehen (, dass Paul den Chef soll haben schlagen wollen.).

Aber in meiner Frage geht es um Zukünftigkeit. Mir ist aufgefallen, dass man "sollen" bei der Wiedergabe von Aussagen über die Zukunft nicht benutzt.

Z. B.:

Kollege sagt: Sabine wird morgen kündigen.
Ich zu einem anderen Kollegen: Hast du gehört? Die Sabine soll morgen kündigen werden. (X)

Mein Gefühl sagt mir sofort, dass das nicht möglich ist. Jetzt ist die Frage: Gibt es Fälle, wo das doch geht? Und wenn das einfach nicht möglich ist, hat jemand eine Idee, warum das so ist?

Kann man sich das irgendwie mit der Zukünftigkeit erklären? Wenn man das Hilfsverb "werden" weglässt und die Zukünftigkeit mit Präsens ausdrückt, dann klingt der Satz mit "sollen" nach einer mündlichen Wiedergabe eines Befehls.

Ich habe gehört, die Sabine soll morgen kündigen.

Das klingt ja schon so, als hätte der Chef das angeordnet oder der Sabine nahegelegt.

Comment: In semantisch eindeutigen Konstellationen wird es aber so benutzt: Morgen soll es Glatteis geben!

Comment: Ja, ich denke, das hängt damit zusammen, dass das eine unpersönliche Konstruktion ist. Man kann dem Glatteis schlecht befehlen zu existieren, besonders nicht mit "es gibt".

Comment: Warum schreibst Du "Ich hätte ein Frage" - Du hast doch klar bewiesen, dass Du eine Frage hast! ;)

Comment: Ich wusste nicht, dass man in diesem Forum jegliche Form der Höflichkeit weglässt. Ich werde in meinem nächsten Beitrag solchen unnötigen Floskeln weglassen. ;-)

Comment: Genau genommen ist es ja auch kein klassisches Forum. ;) Herzlich Wilkommen :)

Comment: Letzter Satz: Das mögliche Missverständnis lässt sich ganz einfach mit einem "angeblich" aus dem Weg schaffen

Comment: Daran habe ich auch schon gedacht, aber ich finde, dass man den Satz immer noch falsch verstehen kann. Wenn ich "Die Sabine soll morgen angeblich kündigen." hören würde, würde mich so ein Satz stutzig machen. Das könnte ja immer noch heißen, dass der Chef das angeblich so von der Sabine verlangt.
Mal abgesehen davon, dass sich das für meine Ohren nicht sauber anhört, stellt sich mir weiterhin die Frage, wieso wir das mit dem Hilfsverb "werden" nicht machen. "Werden" würde die Handlung des Hauptverbs eindeutig in die Zukunft verlegen. Damit wären Missverständnisse gar nicht erst möglich.

Comment: Das würde dann wohl eher als "Sabine wird morgen angeblich kündigen sollen" gesagt werden.

Answer (score 4):

Das ist alles gut beobachtet und m.E. richtig.

1. "Soll" hat mindestens zwei Bedeutungen, was gerade bei Bezug auf die Zukunft je nach Kontext zu einer Uneindeutigkeit führen kann.

   Mögliche Lösungen wären "Sabine wird morgen angeblich kündigen" oder "Ich habe gehört, Sabine werde morgen kündigen".
2. Das Futur mit "werden" kann anscheinend nicht einem weiteren Verb untergeordnet sein. "Sabine könnte kündigen werden" oder "Anton will nächstes Jahr studieren werden" u.ä. gehen auch nicht. Eine Quelle dafür in einer Grammatik habe ich bisher leider nicht gefunden, mir fällt aber auch kein Gegenbeispiel ein.

Comment: Interessant, dass Passiv mit "werden" sehr wohl einem Modalverb untergeordnet sein kann: Sabine soll befördert werden. Mit dem Futur geht das offenbar nicht.

Comment: *m.E.* würde ich ausschreiben, Platz ist genug und Nichtmuttersprachler können es so leichter verstehen.